# class not found when extending class that implements interface in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

class A extends B {}

class B implements C {}

interface C {}
```

the code above throws "Fatal error: Class 'B' not found"...
Is it a php bug? Or?

Environment: "PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Oct 13 2011 23:19:13) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
"

Comment: Is that all the code there is? Also, can't call C if its not created yet (order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have trouble specifically with the order of your class definitions.  As long as the interface is defined in the same file, it can be declared anywhere - but classes must be defined before they can be extended.

The following is perfectly valid order in PHP:

```
class B implements C { ... }
class A extends B { ... }
interface C { ... }
```

There is [a closed bug requesting clarification in the PHP5 docs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51381).

An answer to a similar question ([Does the order of class definition matter in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458756/does-the-order-of-class-definition-matter-in-php)) mentions [Autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).  You may want to look into this if you're using multiple files.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I wonder why can't they scan the whole file at once...

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the classes and interfaces in the wrong order. This is correct:

```
interface C {}

class B implements C {}

class A extends B {}
```