# PHP Fatal error: Class 'X' not found

Tags: php

I am facing a very strange error although it seems that i have done all the requires

Error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Login' not found`

Code:

```
<?php

//Includes...
require_once(__DIR__ . "/base/request.abstract.php");

//Entry point...
try {
    //What should i do ? the class is in the same file so what to do so php recognize it ?
    echo (new Login($_REQUEST['request']))->processRequest();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage()));
}

//Implementation...
class Login extends RequestAbstract
{
    public function processRequest()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: " it seems that i have done all the requires" clearly not, hence the error. not sure what else we could possibly say

Comment: [Check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458756/does-the-order-of-class-definition-matter-in-php)

Comment: and that is why i said `it seems`

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use your `Login` class before it's been declared. Move your class above the try/catch block, and your code will work. [As the manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new), "Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement)."

Defining a class before it is instantiated is a requirement when a Class is implementing an interface.

Comment: @DanielEugen This should not cause the error if the instantiation and declaration are in the same file; http://codepad.viper-7.com/d0IwEY

Comment: @user574632 yea but i was trying to access the class before declaration... that was the problem in my code.